# Nested JavaScript fetches return [object promise] value

Tags: javascript, object, promise, fetch-api

I am trying to render a table in which each row (1,2,3) has expandable rows (a,b,c). Row will get data from API/rows, expandable rows will get data from `API/rowId?expandableRows`. expandable rows will follow it's row when rendered like this:

```
row  col1 col2 col3
1     x    x    x
a     x    x    x
b     x    x    x

2     x    x    x
a     x    x    x  
  
3     x    x    x
a     x    x    x
```

Here is my code:

```
class Table extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={ rowList: [] }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API/rows)
     .then(results=>{return results.json()})
     .then(rows =>{
         let rowList= rows.map(row=> {
             return (
               <react.Fragment>
                <tr><td>{row.info}</td></tr>
                {this.getExpandableRow(row.id).then(exrows=>{return exrows})}
               </react.Fragment>
              )
         })
        this.setState(rowList: rowList);
      })
  }
   
  getExpandableRow(id) {
     return fetch(api/rowid?expandableRows)
               .then(results=>{return results.json();})
               .then(expandData=>{
                     data.map(dat=>{
                       return (
                              <tr><td>expandrow.info</td></tr>
                              )
                     })
                    console.log(expandData)
                })
  }

  render(){
      return (<Table>{this.state.rowList}</Table>)
  }

}
```

Now the problem is I can see expand data in `console.log`, but when calling `getExpandableRows` function in rows loop, no matter use `{this.getExpandableRow(row.id)}` or `{this.getExpandableRow(row.id).then(exrows=>{return exrows})}`,  I got the error:

> Objects are not valid as react child(found:[object promise]), if you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

What should I do to get expandable row data when looping rows?

Comment: Make the functions `async` and `return await fetch(//...` instead.

Comment: `.then(results=>{return results.json();})` has an unnecessary `return` and `.then(expandData=>{...})` is missing a `return`

Comment: You can't use promises in the middle of a React rendered component like that, `{this.getExpandableRow(row.id).then(exrows=>{return exrows})}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I THINK you might be able to get away with this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API/rows)
     .then(results=>{return results.json()})
     .then(async rows =>{
         // this will be an array of promises
         let rowExpPromiseList = rows.map(row=> {
             return this.getExpandableRow(row.id);
         });
         // I believe this will be an array of components at this point
         const rowExpList = await Promise.all(rowExpPromiseList);
         const rowList = rows.map((row, index) => (
               <react.Fragment>
                <tr><td>{row.info}</td></tr>
                {rowExpList[index]}
               </react.Fragment>
              ));
         this.setState(rowList: rowList);
      })
  }
```

You get the expandable rows before you try to render the react components that require them.

Comment: hi TKoL, thank you  very much for your response, after i tried your code, it doesn't give me any error, but expandable rows didn't show up either, I added a console.log after <const RowExpList= await Promise.all(...)>, it just returned comma, not quite sure what's going wrong.

Comment: It just returned a comma? That doesn't make sense, `await Promise.all()` should give an array. Can you not set breakpoints in your application to see what the values are?

Comment: my webstorm debug has some problem, which cannot run properly, but I tried this: 
          let rowExpPromiseList = rows.map(row=> {
 return this.getExpandableRow(row.id); });
         console.log(rowExpPromiseList);
         const rowExpList = await Promise.all(rowExpPromiseList);
         console.log(rowExpList);
the first console returned three items: [object promise] [object promise] [object promise] which make sense as my api have three rows, each row have an array of expandable rows returned , but the second console.log just returned: , ,

Comment: hi TKoL, thank you very much for your help,  I make it work, just changed getExpandableRows to : 
async getExpandableRow(id) {
     const data = await fetch(api/rowid?expandableRows)
               .then(results=>{return results.json();})
               .then(expandData=>{
                           return data})
  const expData =
                     data.map(dat=>{
                       return (
                              <tr><td>expandrow.info</td></tr>
                              )
                     })
                    console.log(expandData)
             
  }